# How can I send an event from parent window to its child window?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, postmessage

I want to send some event/data from parent window to its child window. How can I do so?

I have tried **postMessage**, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has worked now, earlier I was doing some syntax mistake. Here is the correct code for the same.

```
//parent Window
childWindow=window.open("http:/localhost/abcd.php","_blank","width=500,height=500");
childWindow.postMessage('message',"http://localhost:80/child.php");


//child Window
var newUrl='';
window.addEventListener(
 "message",
 function(e) { 

console.log(e.data);//your data is captured in e.data 
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the child window you're referring to is an iFrame, then `postMessage` is the method you're stuck with.

Without seeing any of the code you've tried, it's hard to say what about your particular usage of `postMessage` isn't working – however, here is a link to a [working `postMessage` example from an MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#Example), as well as an [article with a fully functional example](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage) you can dissect the code from.

One of these should be able to show you why your implementation isn't working.